# Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. Try changing the condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I get this when I trying to check for the connection *Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.*
Try changing the condition.

```
if (ConnectivityResult.none) {
        return const LoadingScreen();
      } else {
    Scaffold (...);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        return const LoadingScreen();
      } else {
    Scaffold (...);
}
}
```

Comment: @It'sPhil was it what you looking for?